# Quartz not firing trigger, stays in WAITING state

Tags: triggers, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am creating jobs dynamically whenever server gets a request. Triggers are set to fire only once for every request and have enabled the property withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow for the scheduled trigger.

```
private MutableTrigger getTriggerForOnce() {
    return SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
            .withRepeatCount(0) //This trigger will be fired just once
            .withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow()
            .build();
}
```

```
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
    try {
        logger.info("Starting handler:::");
        JobDataMap jobDataMap = jobExecutionContext.getMergedJobDataMap();
        long id = jobDataMap.getLong(SchedulerConstants.ID);
        
        logger.info("Ending handler:::");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Exception" + ex);
    }
}
```

Quartz properties :: JobStore class :JobStoreTX , 10 threadCount.

Issue :: Since few days back there aren't any new fired triggers. In QRTZ_TRIGGERS table the job stays back in Waiting state.
And it works perfectly in Testing environment but not in Prod environment

I have verified that fields in table like prevFireTime is -1 and nextFireTime is perfectly set in Table and MISFIRE_INSTR is 1. But it does not trigger the job at the scheduled time.

There aren't any exception, or error in log. And I can still create new trigger, but they are never fired.

Can anyone help, what's is the problem, or how can I resolve it?

Comment: i'm having the same issue.  Did you find any resolution?

Comment: Are your schemas identical between your test and production?   On my test environment I ran the latest MySQL scripts to generate the QRTZ_ tables while my production environment has a Quartz schema that is years old.   I compared then and noticed some differences (primarily with indexes).

I dropped the tables from the Test database and copied the schema structure from production and now everything works on test as expected.  

MySQL JDBC, Quartz, etc are identical on both environments.  This seems to suggest there's a glitch in the SQL table init scripts for the latest version of Quartz

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the QRTZ_ tables from your test environment and then copy the structure from your production environment.   That worked for me.  It doesn't explain the root cause but it was a solution (for me at least)